# Unable to center contents of a fieldset

Tags: css, expressionengine, fieldset

am having trouble trying to center the contents of one of my fieldsets.
It has a captcha image, an input field and a submit button. I've tried using margin: 0 auto; but to no avail...

```
<fieldset class="fieldset_submit">


        {if captcha}

        {captcha}

        <p>Please enter the text you see above</p>

        <input type="text" name="captcha" value="" />
        {/if}
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="submit" />

        </fieldset>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.fieldset_submit {
display: block;
width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
border: none;
text-align: center;
padding: 40px;
}


input, select {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 0 20px 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: gray;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

select {height: 35px;}

label {display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;}

fieldset.fieldset_centre textarea {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    color: gray;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.submit {
    width: 100px;
    border: none;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #ff8399;
    color: white;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.submit:hover {cursor: pointer;}

.submit:active {
    position:relative; 
    top:2px
}
```

*Addition:*

Unfortunately despite centering the fieldset the contents don't center when set to display block as per the second method. Strange as both the fiddles display great.

I'm wondering if it's to do with the ee captcha?

Comment: If your local example isn't being centered, you might have some additional rules in your style sheet with a higher weight (i.e. [CSS specificity](http://smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)) that are being inherited, which may be overriding your declarations. Try adding an `ID` to your `fieldset` and adjusting the CSS to match: `<fieldset id="centered">` ...

Answer (score 5):

Using the inheritance of CSS, you can simply *center* the `fieldset` and declare all child elements as block-level, and everything will become centered. Simplified example markup:

**CSS:**

```
.align-center {
    display: block;
    margin: 1.0em auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<fieldset class="align-center">

    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbE6E.jpg" alt="reCAPTCHA" />

    <p>Please enter the text you see above</p>

    <input type="text" name="captcha" value="" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />

</fieldset>
```

I'm a purist and a minimalist and find this approach to be simple and elegant while keeping your markup clean and uncluttered.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/WSsTP/

Comment: I am deliberately nitpicking here, but *centering* in general does not equal to centering *text*. Centering can mean different things -- for instance centering a *left-justified* paragraph of text within a parent block. You won't be able to achieve that using only `text-align`, in fact you'd need to make sure that the computed `text-align` for said paragraph is `left` and not `center`, since you'd want left justification. This will make it impossible for you to center it using `text-align` alone. In addition, `fieldset` elements are quirky and thus notoriously hard to style.